# How to use if statement in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change background color each time when my_div recive class 'selected'. 
So far I've got this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#my_div').hasClass('selected')) {
        $("body").css({backgroundColor: '#111'});
    }
});
```

but it don't work.

What's wrong?

Comment: can you show how it is receiving the class?

Comment: if you're using jQueryUIs `selectable`, i'd listen for the `selectableselected` event.

Comment: Are you looking for [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I want to change background color each time when my_div recive class 'selected'.
```

There is a piece of code which is giving your element the `selected` class. This piece of code effectively changes your element's `class` to be `class = "whatever classes previously existed insertednewclass"`.

One way to do what you're trying to do, is to find the function which is adding/removing the class, and hook into it, for example:

```
myFunction = function(...) {
    $('#my_div').addClass('selected');
    // add more code
    $('#my_div').css({backgroundColor:...});
}
```

I assume your case is not as simple as this. However this is possible even if the function is in an external library, though it's risky if the library changes its internal behavior.

```
// some.function is the function which adds the "selected" class
var oldFunction = some.function;
some.function = function() {
    return oldFunction.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

If you cannot do that and MUST reactively detect a class attribute modification, you can use the deprecated DOM Level 2 mutation events http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents which are vaguely supported in non-IE browsers. You can see if it is supported via `$.bind` in jQuery; if it isn't supported in jQuery, you can use `your_element.addEventListener(...)` which is the native way to do things (which is basically all that jQuery is using under the covers).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom event that will be triggered when the selected class is set or removed.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div').live('myDivChangedState', function(event) {
        if($(event.target).hasClass('selected')) {
           ...
        }
    });
});
```

And than just trigger the event:

```
 $('#my_div').addClass('selected').trigger('myDivChangedState');
 -- OR --
 $('#my_div').removeClass('selected').trigger('myDivChangedState');
```